# Failed to republish to topic in AWS IoT Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

In AWS IoT core, I set up a rule with a republish action to update a thing's shadow (TestThing's shadow) [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7QC1.png)

(I created new IAM role for the action in case you are wondering)

What I was expecting was that the thing's shadow should be updated and nothing should be published to 'testthing/error' when I publish a message to 'testthing/message'. But when I published the following message to 'testthing/message' with AWS IoT MQTT client

`{
  "state":
  {
    "reported":
    {
      "Info":"Hello AWS IoT!"
    }
  }
}`

I got this error from 'testthing/error':

> ...
>
> "failedAction": "RepublishAction",
>
> "failedResource": "/things/TestThing/shadow/update",
>
> "errorMessage": "Failed to republish to topic. Received Server error. The error code is 403. Message arrived on: testthing/message, Topic: /things/TestThing/shadow/update"
>
> ...

If I change the topic to which the message should be republished into 'testthing/destination', everything works fine, no error message was published to 'testthing/error'.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$aws/#** is a reserved topic.

As per AWS Documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-rule-actions.html#w1810aac32c23c35b3b3):
If you are republishing to a reserved topic, one that begins with $ use $$ instead.

**Please replace $ with $$ and try again!**

cheers,
ram